# How to get reference to SSDT Database Project memory model from a Visual Studio Extension?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, sql-server-data-tools, envdte

I'm trying to write a simple extension to the Visual Studio 2013, which should be able to list all tables in a SQL Server Database Project selected by an user of the extension. In order to do that, I need to access in-memory model of the DB project(s). But the only way I found is to load compiled .dacpac file produced by the DB project to a new TSqlModel instance and query it, but I would rather be able work with "live" in-memory representation. I've found this tutorial to SSDT API: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt/archive/2013/12/23/dacfx-public-model-tutorial.aspx, but there is not an example how to connect to the in-memory model within the Visual Studio. I also found a tutorial solving this issue by collecting all files with .sql extension from the current solution and added their content into the TSqlModel instance, but this is not the way I prefer.

Is such thing possible at all? If so, how to do that?

Thank you, 
Michal

Comment: I want to do this as well, the best I can come up with is require a build and open the built dacpac.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Database projects don't provide a Visual Studio service with access to the model right now. However you can simulate this by hooking into project system events and using the APIs to have your own model. Dave Ballantyne shows a static way to do this in [this blog post](http://dataidol.com/davebally/2014/03/29/t4-support-in-ssdt/). If you with to make this more dynamic you can hook up to project events such as project/file added, deleted, changed etc. and update your model based on these events. That is what happens internally in the database project. Note that you should also use the AddOrUpdateObjects API call instead of the one he uses, since this allows you to update a file when it changes:

```
    public void ProcessProjectModels()
    {
        var hostServiceProvider = (IServiceProvider)this.Host;
        var dte = (DTE)hostServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(DTE));

        using (TSqlModel model = new TSqlModel(SqlServerVersion.Sql110, new TSqlModelOptions { }))
        {
            foreach (Project project in dte.Solution)
            {
                IterateThroughProject(project.ProjectItems, model);
            }

            List<TSqlObject> allTables = GetAllTables(model);
            foreach (var table in allTables)
            {
                // Do processing 
            }
        }
    }

    public List<TSqlObject> GetAllTables(TSqlModel model)
    {
        List<TSqlObject> allTables = new List<TSqlObject>();

        var tables = model.GetObjects(DacQueryScopes.All, ModelSchema.Table);
        if (tables != null)
        {
            allTables.AddRange(tables);
        }
        return allTables;
    }

    private void IterateThroughProject(ProjectItems PrjItems, TSqlModel model)
    {
        foreach (ProjectItem PrjItem in PrjItems)
        {
            if (PrjItem.ProjectItems != null)
            {
                IterateThroughProject(PrjItem.ProjectItems, model);
            }
            if (//PrjItem.Object.GetType().ToString() == "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Tools.Package.Project.DatabaseFileNode" && 
                PrjItem.Name.EndsWith(".sql", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                // This is a sql file and will be processed
                // Note: There should be a separate API to read the live contents of this item, to avoid the need to save it
                if (!PrjItem.Saved)
                {
                    PrjItem.Save();
                }
                StreamReader Reader = new StreamReader(PrjItem.FileNames[0]);

                string Script = Reader.ReadToEnd();
                model.AddOrUpdateObjects(Script, PrjItem.Name, null);
            }
        }
    }
```

Note: The reason this feature doesn't have in-build support is that to do it right, the project should either provide a readonly model (no ability to add/update scripts) or ensure that add/update object calls actually affect the relevant script files in the project. It should also support event notifications if you with to do processing on change events (just as the project system supports). If this is something that would be useful to you (as I can imagine it would in this case), then opening a Connect bug or raising it on Visual Studio user voice is the way to get this on the product team radar.

Comment: Thank you for perfect answer, you have confirmed what I was afraid of. The read-only model would be fine for my purposes, since I'm intending to do visualization only, not editing. I think it would be an interesting feature for many developers (for T4 templates, as one example). I was aware of the blogpost you mentioned - this approach has two disadvantages: 1) We are building another same model, which the VS has been already built internaly, 2) I dont know how to not include those sql scripts, which are part of the solution, but not part of the DB project (maintanance/upgrade scripts, etc.).

Comment: T4 template support is  built into the tools right now, but as you've probably noticed it runs against the previously built dacpac for the project. For the other issues you've raised, for 1) it's definitely an issue with this approach and can only be solved by the product adding the support you want. For 2) You should be able to filter projects based on their type. This might be an internal property, but essentially you can get all the projects or IVSHierarchy objects in the solution and there'll be something you can test against to validate the project type. Sorry I can't be any more help

Comment: To find just files which should be included you can get to the properties of each file and use the BuildAction which is "Build" for everything that should be included. (I think it is one of the Properties on ProjectItem - i'll double check tonight)

Answer (score 1):

How to get access to SSDT builded project in-memory model. We are using it to generate logging triggers.
Doing helper t4 first:

```
<#@ import namespace="Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.Model" #>
<#@ assembly name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.Extensions" #>
<#+
    public TSqlModel GetModel()
    {
        return Model;
    }
#>
```

Main t4:

```
<#@ SqlModelDirective processor="SqlModelDirectiveProcessor" #>
<#@ import namespace="Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.Model" #>
<#@ assembly name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.Extensions" #>
<#@ include file="..\Helper.tt" #>
<#
blyablyablya

var allTables = GetAllTables();

blyablyablya
#>
<#+
    // Example method.
    public List<TSqlObject> GetAllTables()
    {
        List<TSqlObject> allTables = new List<TSqlObject>();

        var model = GetModel();
        if (model == null) 
            return allTables;

        var tables = model.GetObjects(DacQueryScopes.All, ModelSchema.Table);
        if (tables != null)
        {
            allTables.AddRange(tables);
        }
        return allTables;
    }
#>
```

Comment: Isn't this what the T4 template does in a sql project?  The OP also already mentioned they can load the pre-built dacpac this way.  They dont want to use the dacpac, they want to use the in memory representation of the project.

Comment: @StingyJack, 

  var model = GetModel();

- here is the in-memory model. But need to build solution first. Or, maybe, i didn't understood what specifically you want to say.

Comment: OP wants the in memory model that the project system is using (its what is  providing things like intellisense). The GetModel() or Model from the Dac stuff will only return a TSqlModel made from a dacpac, The code in your example is working because the SqlModelDirectiveProcessor is likely getting the dacpac path from the project system.

Comment: @StingyJack, At the current time in-memory model is able to be accessed for read-only. This is the only way. And, GetModel () returns the model from memory, not from dacpac.